# Python multiplication, exponent yields different precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

I've got some Python code that I'd like to understand what's going on (see below). I've got the results of the calculations as well.
If I square radius by repeated multiplication I get a different result than if I square radius. If it were rounding, I'd expect a smaller gap between the two calculations. Can someone put me on the right path, please?

```
import math
diameter=float(input('Enter the diameter: '))
radius = diameter / 2.0

area_1 = math.pi * radius * radius
print ("The area is: ", area_1)

area_2 = math.pi * radius**2
print ("The area is: ", area_2)
=========================================================
Enter the diameter: 6.2

The area is:  30.19070540099791**3**

The area is:  30.19070540099791**7**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes from the different way both expressions were calculated:

1. `math.pi * radius * radius` was calculated as:

   a. `tmp = math.pi * radius`

   b. `tmp * radius`
2. `math.pi * radius**2`

   a. `tmp2 = radius**2`

   b. `tmp2 * math.pi`

Mathematically both are equivalent but not so when we are talking about finite precision of floating point types in a computer.

You can read more on the topic [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems) or other sources. The field of [numerical analysis](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Numerical_analysis) (and [numerical methods](https://www.quora.com/What-is-numerical-methods)) deals mostly with these numerical rounding errors in the pursue of finding best algorithms for involved calculations.

---